# I have an IGX_Drop-Down box at the right end of a toolbar, the dropped list extends past the screen. How do I move it to never go off screen?

Tags: angular, dropdown, ignite-ui-angular

I have a simple igx-dropdown at the end of a toolbar.  The button looks fine, but when the dropdown list is displayed, it is oriented on the end of the button, but the contents extend offscreen, like so:
[image]

Is there any way to align the right edge of the dropdown so it never goes off screen no matter how wide the dropdown contents are?

Comment: Please share minimal reproducible code, if psosible a stackblitz with the issue replicated for debugging!